# How to prevent window resizing temporarily?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resize

I have a window which can be resized, but there are some situations when resizing is not possible because of the application state. Is there a way to prevent resizing the window temporarily?

I want to disable resizing by all means available to the users, which include window menu, dragging edges by mouse, user initiated window tiling performed by OS - and perhaps some other I am not aware of?

Comment: Can you capture the WM_SIZE message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [GetWindowLong()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `GWL_STYLE` flag to get the window style and
reset/remove any [styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28VS.85%29.aspx) you need, ie the `WS_THICKFRAME` style so that the window can't be resized.

You apply the new style with [SetWindowLong.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Great. Removing WS_SIZEBOX from the style, setting the new style with SetWindowLong disabled the resizing completely. To be safe, after calling SetWindowLong I update the window using AdjustWindowRectEx / SetWindowPlacement / SetWindowPos / RedrawWindow.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work - I have a window with only WS_CHILD, WS_CLIPCHILDREN and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS and it is still resizable.

Comment: @jheriko, I haven't tested it on child windows. Perhaps the child window can still receive WM_SIZING and WM_SIZE messages.

Answer (score 11):

To retain the look of the window border and still prevent re-size (and cursor change), catch `WM_NCHITTEST`, pass it to DefWindowProc, if the returned code is one of the size constants, change the real return to something else, HTCLIENT for example

Comment: Best answer here - handles the small polish details as well as actually working.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to handle the [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28VS.85%29.aspx) message and set the MINMAXINFO struct so that both min and max size of the window is the current size. Then the user can't resize the window either.

Comment: Setting same sizes on ptMinTrackSize and ptMaxTrackSize works too, but when you click on a resizable border the window "hangs" processing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Following code in the window procedure seems to handle the case of user dragging the window edge/corner:

```
case WM_SIZING:
    RECT &rc = *(LPRECT) lParam;
    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &windowRect);
    rc = windowRect;
    return 0;
```

I did not find anything yet to prevent the system from resizing the window when tiling/cascading windows. I hoped following might do the trick, but it seems it does not:

```
case WM_SIZE:
   return TRUE;
```

I guess I can find similar measure for other cases, but at least I would need to know the exhaustive list of messages which can result in a window changing its size.

Also, while this really prevents the window from resizing, I would rather prevent the user from even initiating the resize, than apparently letting him to resize and then refusing to do so.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work - I've implemented this and instead my window grows a little each time WM_SIZING gets triggered. Also, your code is a little verbose, why not GetWindowRect straight into the lParam address?